# Is it best practice to define global JavaScript objects in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web project that has the following lines of code in it

```
<script>var obj = {...}</script>
<script src='./app.js'></script>
```

`./app.js` loaded by the second script tag uses `obj` defined by the first script tag. You could say that `obj` is a global variable to `./app.js`.

I don't want to define `obj` inside `./app.js` because it's a very large object but is this bad practice to define global variables like this?

Comment: i think that is quite common way to do it, frameworks like angular uses a lot of files that depend on  "global" objects defined in files that are previously loaded

Comment: It's not the cleanest but it's OK. Of course, only if it is justified (The script serves many pages and the object no)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid making `obj` global by passing it into `app.js` somehow.

```
<script src='./app.js'></script>
<script>
   someFunctionToInitAppJs( { 
     // ... 
   })
</script>
```